# maximal subgroup $H(e)$ of semigroup $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, semigroups

Let $e$ be an idempotent in a semigroup $S$. The union of all subgroups of $S$ containing $e$ is called the maximal subgroup of $S$ containing $e$ and is denoted by $H(e)$. We know that $H(e)$ is actually a subgroup of $S$ with idedntity $e$. I want to prove:
$$H(e)=\{t\in eSe: e\in St\cap tS\}$$

I think I should prove the right hand side is a group containing $H(e)$.

Comment: Can you show that $H(e)$ is contained in the right hand side? That;s not too hard.

Comment: @DerekHolt well, if $t\in H(e)$ then $t=ete\in eSe$ and since $H(e)$ is a group with identity $e$ there is $t'\in H(e)\subset S$ such that $tt'=t't=e\in St\cap tS$ so $H(e)\subset RHS$. True? But we should show RHS is a subgroup to get equality. Why RHS is a subgroup?could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the RHS is a group, suppose that $t \in $RHS. Then $e \in St \cap tS$ implies that there exist $s_1,s_2 \in S$ with $s_1t =ts_2 = e$ and then $s_1e = s_1ts_2=es_2$.

Also $t \in eSe \Rightarrow te = et =t$, so $tes_2 = s_1et = e$ and hence $s_1e=es_2$ is a $2$-sided inverse to $t$.

For closure, clearly $t,u \in eSe \Rightarrow tu \in eSe$, and $tu$ has inverse $u^{-1}t^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, But I don't know why $t\in eSe$ implies $te=et=e$? I think we just have $te=et=t$.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo - I've corrected it.